# java netty/nio connect generates an excessive amount of interrupts on windows 2003

Tags: java, nio, netty

i am using netty nio for client server communication on a single machine.

the same client/server programs work fine on many servers except on certain windows 2003 machines.

if the server is not running and the client tries to connect (resulting as expected in an exception after some timeout)  the number of interrupts on the server increases dramatically.

normally the number of interrupts (as displayed by the windows performance gui) is on avg 300/s. when the client tries to connect the interrupts go up to about 1000/s.

the interrupts/s remain high as long as the client is running, even when it does not try to reconnect and it remains high once it is able to connect.

this does not happen if the client can connect to the server on first try.

the increased interrupt count results in a strong drift of the server clock.

**any ideas or suggestions on what is going on and how to avoid it ?**

after reading:
http://blogs.technet.com/b/markrussinovich/archive/2008/04/07/3031251.aspx

I run KernRate with the following results:

when client tries to connect:

```
P0     K 0:00:00.015 ( 0.2%)  U 0:00:00.031 ( 0.4%)  I 0:00:07.265 (99.4%)  DPC
 0:00:00.000 ( 0.0%)  Interrupt 0:00:00.000 ( 0.0%)
   Interrupts= 6117, Interrupt Rate= 837/sec.


Context Switches     ,       307153,         42004/sec.
System Calls         ,       404125,         55265/sec.
Page Faults          ,         1050,         144/sec.
I/O Read Operations  ,          143,         20/sec.
I/O Write Operations ,          386,         53/sec.
I/O Other Operations ,         1407,         192/sec.
I/O Read Bytes       ,        14712,         103/ I/O
I/O Write Bytes      ,        49575,         128/ I/O
I/O Other Bytes      ,       182356,         130/ I/O


 Module                                Hits   msec  %Total  Events/Sec
 intelppm                              11144       7311    97 %    38106962
 ntoskrnl                                196       7311     1 %      670222
 hal                                      69       7311     0 %      235945
 win32k                                   53       7311     0 %      181233
 ramirr2                                   6       7311     0 %       20517
 afd                                       2       7311     0 %        6839
 tcpip                                     2       7311     0 %        6839
 Ntfs                                      1       7311     0 %        3419
 bxvbdx                                    1       7311     0 %        3419
```

when the client process is not running:

```
P0     K 0:00:00.015 ( 0.3%)  U 0:00:00.000 ( 0.0%)  I 0:00:04.546 (99.7%)  DPC
 0:00:00.000 ( 0.0%)  Interrupt 0:00:00.000 ( 0.0%)
   Interrupts= 2213, Interrupt Rate= 485/sec.


                              Total      Avg. Rate
Context Switches     ,         9398,         2060/sec.
System Calls         ,        29104,         6379/sec.
Page Faults          ,         2158,         473/sec.
I/O Read Operations  ,          130,         28/sec.
I/O Write Operations ,          273,         60/sec.
I/O Other Operations ,          619,         136/sec.
I/O Read Bytes       ,        12029,         93/ I/O
I/O Write Bytes      ,        37754,         138/ I/O
I/O Other Bytes      ,        92840,         150/ I/O

 Module                                Hits   msec  %Total  Events/Sec
 intelppm                               7208       4561    99 %    39508879
 ntoskrnl                                 20       4561     0 %      109625
 win32k                                   10       4561     0 %       54812
 hal                                       4       4561     0 %       21925
 ramirr2                                   3       4561     0 %       16443
 tcpip                                     3       4561     0 %       16443
 Ntfs                                      1       4561     0 %        5481
```

-- Ron

Comment: What's the client's retry interval when connecting? You should double it on every attempt, and you should start with a value of at least 10 seconds, as the TCP stack will do its own timeouts and retries below your threshold, at intervals starting with about 3 seconds.

Comment: thanks for the reply, the reconnect intervall is currently at 1 sec for one application and 5 sec for the other. I will try setting it higher and will post my findings.

Comment: i tested with netty oio on the client and similar effect. we also have the retry interval set to 1 min. still same effect.

Comment: so *raise* it, as I said, and double it each failure, as I said. One second is ridiculously low for any TCP timeout.

Comment: yes, we raised it to 1 minute. but no change.

Comment: In that case I suggest you have a hardware problem. Try swapping the NIC.

Answer (score 1):

This problem is solved in the bugfix for bug [356 - Bug in HashedWheelTimer.waitForNextTick() ?](https://github.com/netty/netty/issues/356)

This bug was caused by windows generating an interrupt when java called Thread.sleep() and is solved by not sleeping if the time is lower than 10 ms.

After applying this change the interrupt rate remains constant.